# Disable Session redirect in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

On a CakePHP app when a user logs in, it redirects the user to either a previous visited action that requires authentication or to a default location specified by `loginRedirect` but all of this is hidden in the session value and stored until deleted.

I would like to disable this and instead replace it with query strings in the url such as for example `domain.com/users/login?back?=/posts/add`

This is to make sure the user always knows what they are trying to access and prevents them from being sent to locations that are saved in the session from previous visits and may not necessarily be the location they wish to visit...

Can anyone help? Thanks

**EDIT: I have disbaled `autoRedirect` which DOES disable the Auth.redirect session key so now I need to build my own query string can anyone help with this?**

Comment: if you already turned off autoRedirect then what is the problem? dont you know how to pass params in the url, or dont you know how to read them back in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

in $this->Form->create() pass the url option with $this->referer() in it as a param, you will need to url encode it I guess.

you can then pick it up again in the login action and use $this->redirect($thatParam) to do there.

Comment: Hi, can you show you some code examples? I'm struggling with this at the moment. Cheers

Comment: Also why would I put it inside the form? wouldn't I just check if the query exists or not in the login method and then redirect them if it exits or default to another url if it does not... so not sure what the adding to the form is need for? Thanks